# how can we run .net core c# Tesseract code on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, tesseract

I have the following code to extract text from an image using Tesseract. This code is developed in .Net Core C# and is working perfectly fine on a windows machine, However this is not working on a linux servre.
What am i missing here? Do I need to install Tesseract (apt-get install tesseract) on the linux server, I did not install Tesseract on windows machine, the code is using the dll directly, I believe Linux machine too should use the dll references to execute the code.

Below is the code:

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine("tessdata_folder", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
     using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(image_path))
     {
         /*
          Remaining code goes here
         */
     }
}
```

The code is failing at below line on Linux machine with this error **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**
The files in **tessdata_folder** are same the ones i used for windows machine, would these files cause the issue, If 'yes', where can i find linux compatible tessdata.

**using (var engine = new TesseractEngine("tessdata_folder_path", "eng", EngineMode.Default))**

Below is the full stack trace of the error.

```
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
 at InteropDotNet.InteropRuntimeImplementer.CreateInstance[T]()
 at Tesseract.Interop.LeptonicaApi.Initialize()
 at Tesseract.Interop.TessApi.Initialize()
 at Tesseract.Interop.TessApi.get_Native()
 at Tesseract.TesseractEngine..ctor(String datapath, String language, EngineMode engineMode, IEnumerable`1 configFiles, IDictionary`2 initialOptions, Boolean setOnlyNonDebugVariables)
 at **web_api_controller_name**.OCRImage(String image_path, Int32 page_id, String page_img_path) in ***.cs file_name***:line 606
```